# How to convert a set of row data in to a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the input dataset in the following format
[input data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tymtS.jpg)

Input data was generated by the following code snippet.

```
   for i in range (0,10):
        my_list = df1.iloc[i].split(",")
        for x in my_list:
                if x in Waterbodies:
                    print(i,"Waterbodies")    
                if x in Beaches:
                    print(i,"Beaches")
```

And I want them to be added to a dataframe like in the below format.

[output data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UObwj.jpg)

I tried several examples and neither didn't work.What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Cat'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
ID
0    [Waterbodies, Beaches]
1    [Waterbodies, Beaches]
3                 [Beaches]
7    [Waterbodies, Beaches]
8             [Waterbodies]
Name: Cat, dtype: object
```

Here is a MCVE:

```
d = pd.Series(['Waterbodies','Beaches','Waterbodies','Beaches','Beaches','Waterbodies','Beaches','Waterbodies'],index=[0,0,1,1,3,7,7,8])

d = d.rename('Cat')

d.index.name = 'id'

d.groupby('id').apply(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id                     Cat
0   0  [Waterbodies, Beaches]
1   1  [Waterbodies, Beaches]
2   3               [Beaches]
3   7  [Waterbodies, Beaches]
4   8           [Waterbodies]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But when I tried to get the categories as a list an error occurred as TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I found that the same can be done by using df.groupby('ID')['Cat'].apply(tuple) by converting it in to a tuple. Thanks for the support by giving a clue. :)

Comment: What does df.info() output?  What are your dtypes?

Comment: df.info() gives "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'". And dtypes outputs "dtype('O')".

Comment: @ChamaniShiranthika I've updated the post with a full example using pd.Series.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot